# REST API receives 'null' from XMLHttpRequest - same request with Postman works?

Tags: javascript, json, rest, xmlhttprequest

I have a very basic `XMLHttpRequest` which looks like this:

```
var requestBody = JSON.stringify(
{
   "parameter_1": ["940mbodmgpg04", "curnv_dsiofpe"],
   "parameter_2": {
        "sub_par": {
            "sub_par-entry":"en_489vb", 
            "sub_par-second-entry":"avop30kdm", 
            "toggler": ["ovofpvm235", "23rfdkvo_SDgop"]
            }
        }
}
);

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "http://localhost:4000/api/fontstabilizer/vorq3", true);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // do some stuff
};

req.send(requestBody);
```

However, when I send this to the REST API, it receives `null` as the body. I tested the exact `requestBody` JSON in Postman, chose `application/json` as the `content-type` and added the `url` to the endpoint and it worked. Using Postman, I was able to connect to the REST API (where I see my JSON object being received) and then I got the needed response back.

I don't understand why Postman works fine, but `XMLHttpRequest` doesn't. Is Postman using some kind of extra processing when sending the JSON object? Am I missing something in my `XMLHttpRequest`?

Any ideas to try would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the request method is GET or HEAD, the body parameter is ignored and the request body is set to null.

Comment: You could serialize the body into GET parameter format and just add it to the end of the URL. Or you could try changing it to POST.